# PHP-FPM Error - keep getting “Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 107374182448 bytes) in ”

Tags: php

the product environment ,all requrest return error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 107374182448 bytes) in /www/wwwroot/xxx/framework/bootstrap.inc.php on line 108
```

then set memory_limit to -1

```
ini_set('memory_limit',-1);
```

return

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 2097152) (tried to allocate 107374182448 bytes) in...
```

when I restart php-fpm service ,It was OK ,but it will happen again after a while.

My PHP version is PHP 7.3 ,open Opcache.

Comment: Something you're doing is trying to use up 100+ *gigabytes* of RAM. You need to find that.

Comment: I dont know why It will try to allocate 100GB RAM, But restart php-fpm ,It was OK. How can I debug It ?

Comment: What triggers this error? Does it happen always, regardless of which PHP code are you running?

Comment: $_W['siteroot'] = htmlspecialchars($_W['sitescheme'] . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $sitepath);

Answer (score 0):

setting `pm = ondemand` in `php-fpm.conf` may solve the problem.